# Linked SQL table in Access 2003 (!) not updatable

Tags: permissions, sql-server-2008-r2, ms-access-2003, database-permissions

I'm working in a legacy app for the moment, upgrading Access 2003 to link to SQL Server tables (2008 R2 or later).  With tables linked by code, I can insert, but not update or delete.  I've tried everything on the web, no dice.  Details below.

*Being terse so not tl;dr.*

Tables first created using upsizing wizard.  In use, app has to connect to different ones in same schema, so can't just set and forget.  Can't do local DSN's, many installs, though DSN file is possible.  But problems there too, DSN not found.  Details later.

Before the rest:  Soon I'm further updating this app to Access 2016 or so.  If this is different enough / easier there, I'll wait a few days.  Maybe someone could suggest the best refsite for that.

*** problem details follow ***

Using a DSN and the UI to link a table, I get an editable table.  Hurray.

But when I use the code below (found on every refsite), link is made but only selecting and inserting work.  Everything else fails fails fails, no matter what.

```
Public Function LinkToSqlTable(sqlInstance As String, sqlDb As String, 
    sqlTableName As String, localTableName As String)  

Dim linked As New TableDef

' ***factored-out functionality, known to work: reader can ignore*** '
DeleteTable localTableName

' connection-string steps, placeholders replaced by args '
Dim sCnx As String
sCnx = "ODBC;Driver=SQL Server;Server=_instance_;" & _
    "Database=_db_;Integrated Security=SSPI"
sCnx = Replace(sCnx, "_instance_", sqlInstance)
sCnx = Replace(sCnx, "_db_", sqlDb)


' linked-table steps '
Set linked = CurrentDb.CreateTableDef(localTableName)
linked.Connect = sCnx
linked.SourceTableName = sqlTableName
CurrentDb.TableDefs.Append linked


' ui '
RefreshDatabaseWindow

End Function
```

*** ID column or permissions? ***

I thought the problem was lack of identity column originally,  I added one, but no change.  At least now I have a PK field like I should.  ;-)

When I manually link table, UI demands to know the ID column.  So could it still be it?  Fine, but how do I set that in code?  Searches revealed nothing.

I assume then it's permissions as sites etc. say.  I also took all the steps I could think of to fix that.  No dice.

*** things I've tried ***

Aside from the ID-column stuff I said before, these things (not in order):

- Since DSN saved as a file, tried using it as exampled, in cnx string.  Fail.
- Used DSN contents, carefully winnowed & translated, in cnx string.  Fail.
- Used connection string from the table that I had connected manually with DSN.  Fail.
- Changed driver in cnx string across all major options, even omitted it.  Fail.
- Changed security in cnx to Integrated Security=SSPI and other options, and omitted entirely.  Fail.
- I added my actual local user as exampled, with and without password.  Fail.

(Previous few options tried across earlier options, though not 100% coverage.)

- In SQL Server, using SSMS, I tried security power:

  - Added SQS-authentication login to the instance
  - Matching user to the default db seen here
  - Gave that login-user read and write permissions in db here (plus others, sometimes)
  - Added matching id & pw to the cnx string.  Fail.
- I tried setting up this db in SQS to have let-everyone-do-everything "security" temporarily.  Fail.
- This, that, and the other thing.  Everything fail!!

So a permissions issue?  Some way to use DSN file after all?  Mismatched permission settings in my cnx string?  Boneheaded oversight?  Something else that I've missed?  I'm pretty good at both SQL Server and Access, but only at a basic level in their security stuff and connection strings are the devil.

*** retrieved table properties ***

Just in case they help, I retrieved these (after objects added to TableDefs collection).

** This one, done in UI and with DSN and this-is-ID-field, worked with editing: **

```
Name = dbo_tblSendTo
Updatable = False
DateCreated = 4/19/2016 11:11:40 AM
LastUpdated = 4/19/2016 11:11:42 AM
Connect = ODBC;Description=SQL Server tables for TeleSales 5;DRIVER=SQL Server Native Client 10.0;SERVER=(local)\sqlexpress;Trusted_Connection=Yes;APP=Microsoft Office 2003;WSID=CMSERVER;DATABASE=TS5_General;
Attributes = 536870912
SourceTableName = dbo.tblSendTo
RecordCount = -1
ValidationRule = 
ValidationText = 
ConflictTable = 
ReplicaFilter =
```

** And this one, from table linked via code, didn't: **

```
Name = tblSendTo
Updatable = False
DateCreated = 4/19/2016 11:17:51 AM
LastUpdated = 4/19/2016 11:17:51 AM
Connect = ODBC;Description=SQL Server tables for TeleSales 5;DRIVER=SQL Server Native Client
    > 10.0;SERVER=(local)\sqlexpress;Trusted_Connection=Yes;APP=Microsoft Office 2003;WSID=CMSERVER;DATABASE=TS5_General;
Attributes = 536870912
SourceTableName = dbo.tblSendTo
RecordCount = -1
ValidationRule = 
ValidationText = 
ConflictTable = 
ReplicaFilter =
```

*** my plea ***

So.....   Please someone help me out.  I don't like feeling stupid like this, and regrettably I need to do this instead of replacing it with .NET code or similar.

Thanks, anyone who can...
Ed.

Comment: So, update, I got it working but it's not **truly** solved...

_Not **truly** meaning it works but I don't know why.  "Things that go away by themselves can come back by themselves," as Word used to warn us._

I speculated that maybe I needed to have the DSN file I made in the default location for them.  Well, I set that up, and then for the hell of it I got the table properties for the manually-linked table there.  <contd next comment>

Comment: And I applied them.  And this time it worked... !!!  So I have no idea what this is about.  Here's the different and working connection string, but I'd still love to know what **exactly** makes this one work when the other one doesn't.  I'm pretty sure some of it is fluff, like the "description=".  **Any expert insights there anyone, please?**


"ODBC;Description=SQL Server tables for TeleSales 5;DRIVER=SQL Server Native Client 10.0;SERVER=(local)\sqlexpress;Trusted_Connection=Yes;APP=Microsoft Office 2003;WSID=CMSERVER;DATABASE=TS5_General;"
<end extended comment>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Alas, I am able to answer my own question.**

**edited a little since first posted in reply to HansUp's comments**

I had added an identity column to the table that I couldn't edit.  However, I had not set it up **as a primary key**.  It turns out that using `identity` doesn't make something a primary key automatically.

But the latter, making it primary key using either of the 2 possible DDL syntaxes, is crucial.  Since I thought I had dealt with the *no edits without unique key* problem, I focused on permissions.

All of the permissions things here, then, are just a sideshow.

The upshot of this is to be sure to add an identity column ***and make it a primary key*** if for some reason your original table schema didn't have that.

If I have the time, I will be trimming the question to reflect what I've discovered.

Comment: Ha, yes.  I made the assumption the first pass through that adding a field with `identity` specified also made it a PK field in DDL.  So, live and learn.  I am adding it now with `primary key` inlined after `identity` and the usual `not null`, although I'm aware that for more sophisticated uses, I should use `add constraint` and all that. ... 

BTW, I'm glad that someone else out there is paying attention, **HansUp**.  Thanks for commenting.  I'll edit my answer to clarify a little.

... The upshot is, DDL hasn't been my strong suit in SQL... better late than never.